# How to make pagination for Laravel resource API

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a model that I paginate like this:

```php
$reserve = PropertyCalendar::paginate(1);
return new ReserveResource($reserve);
```

I also made an API that responds with resource, and in Vue component I'll calling it with `axios.get`.

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
  return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

Here is the API response:

```
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "property_id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "payable_price": 11,
      "reserve_start": "2019-03-30 00:00:00",
      "reserve_end": "2019-04-01 00:00:00",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null
    }
  ],
  "first_page_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/reserve?page=1",
  "from": 1,
  "last_page": 2,
  "last_page_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/reserve?page=2",
  "next_page_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/reserve?page=2",
  "path": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/reserve",
  "per_page": 1,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "to": 1,
  "total": 2
}
```

Now I want to know how can I make pagination for it, I can't make it with traditional Laravel pagination as it is in Vue component.

```js
loadReserves() {
  axios.get("../api/reserve", {
    params: {
      commentId: this.comment_id
    }
  }).then((response) => (this.comments = response.data.data));
},
```

Now I am showing data but I want to paginate it like what in the API.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you using any UI Library like [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/), [element-ui](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element) or [buefy](https://buefy.org/#/)?

Comment: @CloudSohJunFu no nothing i use nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using bootstrap is not a problem for your use case, I'd recommend using this vue plugin.

I am using it myself with great results.

https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination

Comment: does it work when u use pagination on api ??? i mean when u have the next page adderss like   "last_page_url": "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/reserve?page=2",
 for example ???

Answer (score 0):

This is some example with bootstrap showing how you can use Laravel pagination with Vue.js

[Example](https://jsbin.com/raheqomeki/3/edit?html,js,output).

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item" :class="{disabled: response.current_page === 1}">
    <a class="page-link" @click="previous">Previous</a>
  </li>
  <li 
      v-for="number in response.last_page"
      class="page-item"
      :class="{active: response.current_page === number}"
      >
    <a class="page-link" @click="navigateTo(number)">{{ number }}</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item" :class="{disabled: response.current_page === response.last_page}">
    <a class="page-link" @click="next">Next</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```